# PayPal IPN Sent with 200 response but my database is not updating

Tags: php, apache, pdo, http-post, paypal-ipn

I am trying to implement the PayPal IPN solution. I am checking  the IPN History page of my saccount and all messages are being sent with a 200 response. The problem is that nothing in my DB is being updated or inserted.

My environment is:

- PHP 7.4
- Apache
- CentOS 8

I also tried to log something to a file but I am failing to do so. This is the first time I try to implement the PayPal IPN and I am very confused.

This is my current code:

```
 <?php

class PaypalIPN
{
    /** @var bool Indicates if the sandbox endpoint is used. */
    private $use_sandbox = false;
    /** @var bool Indicates if the local certificates are used. */
    private $use_local_certs = true;

    /** Production Postback URL */
    const VERIFY_URI = 'https://ipnpb.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
    /** Sandbox Postback URL */
    const SANDBOX_VERIFY_URI = 'https://ipnpb.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';

    /** Response from PayPal indicating validation was successful */
    const VALID = 'VERIFIED';
    /** Response from PayPal indicating validation failed */
    const INVALID = 'INVALID';

    const DEBUG = true;
   

    /**
     * Sets the IPN verification to sandbox mode (for use when testing,
     * should not be enabled in production).
     * @return void
     */
    public function useSandbox()
    {
        $this->use_sandbox = true;
    }

    /**
     * Sets curl to use php curl's built in certs (may be required in some
     * environments).
     * @return void
     */
    public function usePHPCerts()
    {
        $this->use_local_certs = false;
    }

    /**
     * Determine endpoint to post the verification data to.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPaypalUri()
    {
        if ($this->use_sandbox) {
            return self::SANDBOX_VERIFY_URI;
        } else {
            return self::VERIFY_URI;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Verification Function
     * Sends the incoming post data back to PayPal using the cURL library.
     *
     * @return bool
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function verifyIPN()
    {
        if ( ! count($_POST)) {
            throw new Exception("Missing POST Data");
        }

        $raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
        $raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
        $myPost = array();
        foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
            $keyval = explode('=', $keyval);
            if (count($keyval) == 2) {
                // Since we do not want the plus in the datetime string to be encoded to a space, we manually encode it.
                if ($keyval[0] === 'payment_date') {
                    if (substr_count($keyval[1], '+') === 1) {
                        $keyval[1] = str_replace('+', '%2B', $keyval[1]);
                    }
                }
                $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
            }
        }

        // Build the body of the verification post request, adding the _notify-validate command.
        $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
        foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {
            $value = urlencode($value);
            $req .= "&$key=$value";
        }

        // Post the data back to PayPal, using curl. Throw exceptions if errors occur.
        $ch = curl_init($this->getPaypalUri());
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);

        // This is often required if the server is missing a global cert bundle, or is using an outdated one.
        if ($this->use_local_certs) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, __DIR__ . "/cert/cacert.pem");
        }
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'User-Agent: PHP-IPN-Verification-Script',
            'Connection: Close',
        ));
        $res = curl_exec($ch);
        if ( ! ($res)) {
            $errno = curl_errno($ch);
            $errstr = curl_error($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            throw new Exception("cURL error: [$errno] $errstr");
        }

        $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
        $http_code = $info['http_code'];
        if ($http_code != 200) {
            throw new Exception("PayPal responded with http code $http_code");
        }

        curl_close($ch);

        // Check if PayPal verifies the IPN data, and if so, return true.
        if ($res == self::VALID) {           
            // crea el LOG
            if($this->DEBUG == true) {
                error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "IPN Verification: $req ". PHP_EOL, 3, 'ipn.log');
            }
            return true;
        } else {
            // crea el LOG
            if($this->DEBUG == true) {
                error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "IPN Verification: $req ". PHP_EOL, 3, 'ipn.log');
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}

$ipn = new PaypalIPN();
// Use the sandbox endpoint during testing.
$ipn->useSandbox();
$verified = $ipn->verifyIPN();
if ($verified) {
    /*
     * Process IPN
     * A list of variables is available here:
     * https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/
     */
    $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
    $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
    $custom = $_POST['custom'];
    $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
    $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
    $receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
    $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
    $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
    $item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
    
    if($payment_amount >= '20') {
        // Donation is $20 or higher, so let's add 20% to the coins.
        $coins = $payment_amount*10*1.2;
    }
    else {
        // Donation is less than $20, no bonus.
        $coins = $payment_amount*10;
    }

    // Add E. Coins
    $acc = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=myhost;Database=mydb", "myusr", "mypass");

    $add = $acc->prepare("UPDATE CashAccount SET Cash = Cash + :coins WHERE ID = :account");
    $add->bindParam(':coins', $coins, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $add->bindParam(':account', $custom, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $add->execute();

    // Log the donation
    $db = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=myhost;Database=mydb", "myusr", "mypass");
    
    $method = 'PayPal';
    $query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO logs (Account, Amount, Coins, Method, Date, Email) VALUES (:account, :amount, :coins, :method, GETDATE(), :email)");
    $query->bindParam(':account', $custom, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(':amount', $payment_amount, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindParam(':coins', $coins, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindParam(':method', $method, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(':email', $payer_email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->execute();


} 
// Reply with an empty 200 response to indicate to paypal the IPN was received correctly.
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
```

I also enbled IPN Notifications in my Business/Sandbox accounts and updated the URL to `http://example.com/paypal_ipn.php`

Here is my IPN History from the PayPal sandbox.

[image]

Maybe someone here can point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Where have you looked for your ipn.log file?

PHP may not have write permissions to the current directory.

What happens if you turn on errors/warnings and access your IPN listener from a browser? Does it print errors to the screen, about not being able to open ipn.log for writing?

You may need to use an absolute path to a directory PHP does have permissions to write to, for example:

```
error_log("This is a message!", 3, "/tmp/ipn.log");
```